# draw continuous graph in windows for using c#

Tags: c#

I want to draw continuous graph in windows for i want library like zgraph but continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Zgraph can also draw realtime data.
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Display_Dynamic_or_Real-Time_Data

Answer (score 0):

you can use MS chart control library.
Download it in this [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)

It's easy to use and has many samples online.
don't forget to mark as answerd!